# PowerBI - Cumulative Total with Multiple Criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

New to PowerBI, so forgive me for the description here. I'm working with a dataset of retail headcount sensors, which gives me a table of locations, timestamps, and a count of shoppers:

```
Room     TimeStamp     Count_In
123      3/13/2019     8
456      4/4/2019      9
123      3/28/2019     11
123      3/18/2019     11
456      3/22/2019     3
etc...
```

I'm trying to calculate a running total for each "room" over time. The overall running total column is easy:

```
C_In =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sheet1[In] ),
    ALL ( Sheet1 ),
    Sheet1[Time] <= EARLIER ( Sheet1[Time] )
)
```

But I'm unable to figure out how to add that second filter, making sure that I'm only summing for each distinct location. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ALL` function removes all context on `Sheet1`, try using `ALLEXCEPT` to keep the row context of the `Room`.

```
C_In =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sheet1[In] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Room] ),
    Sheet1[Time] <= EARLIER ( Sheet1[Time] )
)
```

Comment: How might one calculate a cumulative total with multiple factors, such as Room, and hypothetically, "floor," "brand," and/or "manager"?

Comment: @Ben You can add other columns like `ALLEXCEPT ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Room], Sheet1[Floor], Sheet1[Brand] )`.